# Touch functionalities on ubuntu 15.10 desktop?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, 15.04

I have a 2-in-1 laptop (Lenovo yoga 3 pro) that came pre-installed with windows 8.1.  I removed windows completely to help me adjust faster to ubuntu (successfully, and am happy with the new os).  However, there are a few things that I can't quite figure out yet, mostly having to do with the 2-in-1-ness of my computer...

1. auto-rotate.  windows had this capability, and now I feel spoiled.  if I switch to tablet mode, I generally would hold it vertically (upright).  I know if I go into the settings somewhere, or type a command in the terminal, the screen will rotate.  however, I don't want to have to do this every time I switch the orientation I am using the computer with.  is there any way I can make this occur automatically?
2. on-screen keyboard.  I really like the on-screen keyboard that comes with ubuntu, its stretchable and doesn't look strange on my smaller high-res screen.  however, I still have to go into a settings menu to toggle it on or off.  is there any way to make it pop up when I click in a textbox, or am prompted for text, and then disappear when I select outside of the textbox?
3. anything else I may be forgetting that is handy with a laptop/tablet?  I don't use the testing builds, but is there anything in the works for 2-in-1's (I've noticed there being a lot more out now) to make ubuntu more adaptive?  This is just my two cents, but I think ubuntu needs to get ahead of the curve on this fast...one of the benefits of linux OS's in general is that they can update rapidly and come with a huge array of capabilities, but I feel kind of stuck here with my 2-in-1.
4. as a final option, how dumbed-down is the ubuntu touch OS?  is this my issue?  I am unfamiliar with it, does it have all the same capabilities as the desktop variant?

Update:
for the keyboard, I have found out a little more about onboard, but I'm not sure it's a permanent solution.  in the dash, type "onboard" and click "onboard settings."  from here, ensure "auto-show when editing text" is checked, and click settings next to it.  then, I check "hide when using a physical keyboard" and adjust "stay hidden" to 1 minute.  this is still a subpar solution.  the keyboard does not appear when I am prompted for text everywhere, such as in the chrome address bar.  it does come up when I open up the dash, which is a workaround, but still not ideal.  it should simply appear when necessary, and disappear when it's just in the way.

Comment: To add one more: ubuntu touch nicely support zoom gestures, which don't seem to work on a desktop, neither on the touchpad nor touchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Answers and remarks:

(1) I can't make the screen rotate. What is the command?

(2) Open the dash. Type onscreen. Drag onscreen into left hand Unity application menu, thereby always making the onscreen keyboard but one onscreen button press away.

(2-hint) in onscreen settings->general click auto-show, not that this always makes the keyboard autoshow but sometimes it does.

(3) Well said. If(!) Canonical walks its talk then Ubuntu would recognise it was on a Yoga 3 Pro and auto-configure to suit. And it would know about all four physical configs and autorotate the screen as necessary. Or there would be an apt-get deb package to do same.

(4) Correct me but Ubuntu Touch is not suitable for the Yoga 3 Pro. Correct me?!

Comment: I would assume ubuntu touch is not suitable for the yoga 3 pro, tailored more towards simple tablets, but I haven't used it.