# Ubuntu Touch for computer

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am about to inherit a computer from my wife's aunt. The computer is a Windows 7 variety touch screen, all-in-one computer. I guess I'm just curious to see if Ubuntu is properly formatted for this kind of computer. I'm aware that there is a tablet and smartphone version of the OS, but I need to know if it is equally adaptable to a touch screen computer as well.

Future thanks,
Orion

Comment: The desktop version has support for touch gestures. I recommend you do *not* use the phone/tablet versions. I think the desktop version should be perfectly fine on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Look through this WIKI, and see if your hardware is there.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen

But I would say, make a backup of the system, and try it out, the worst that could happen is it does not work, and seeing as it sounds like this is just a have fun machine and see if it works machine, then you really lose nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu 15.10 on a Samsung ATIV 700, which is one of those 2-in-1 PC/Tablet things and it works well.

Drivers for the touch screen worked out of the box. The only drivers that I don't have are for the ambient light sensor and .

The touch screen itself is somewhat useful in the desktop environment. Unity has some multitouch gestures (e.g. for moving windows around) and some apps distinguish between touch and clicks while some do not. For example, in the file browser a touch will scroll while a click and drag will select. Chromium does this too, making for quite a nice browsing experience.

That being said, it doesn't perform well as a tablet, despite Canonical going on about "convergence" for so long. There are a few too many things that are a very difficult or impossible, without a mouse or a right click that it's not really worth removing the dock. The onscreen keyboard is a pain to set up properly (though is fine for actually typing).

It is probably possible to get the phone/tablet "Ubuntu Touch" software on there, but it's far less powerful than the desktop environment.

See [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659227/touch-functionalities-on-ubuntu-15-10-desktop?rq=1) for another account.